# Displaying an object from api in Angular 6

Tags: php, laravel, angular6

Is there a way to iterate odd keys with Angular 6? and display names as expected?

Object from API

```
users = {
   32: {
     name: foo,
     key: value    
   },
   54: {
     name: bar,
     key: value
   },
   110: {
     name: wakanda,
     key: value
   }
}
```

Output HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
   {{ user.name }}
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use the keyvalue pipe together with two elements, one for *ngFor and one for *ngIf as those can't be on the same element.

Comment: Or even better, prepare the data using a getter so you can do it with just one regular ngFor loop.